# iphone 6 plus - Is the resistor R0601 important?

Tags: pcb, resistance, schematics, cpu, iphone

1. What is the resistor R0601 important for?
2. Can a iphone 6 plus work without it ?
3. What is the meaning of the code (ZQ) in the iphone schematic?

[image: Schematci]

Thanks

Comment: Unless you are lucky enough to have your question answered by Designer of this circuit, I reckon it is nearly impossible to know the consequences of removing this resistor without having access to the MCU's datasheet.

Comment: ZQ seems to suggest calibration resistor for line terminations. You see it a lot on DDR interfaces.

Comment: The question really is why?

Comment: the probem is i reball the iphone 6 plus cpu and i lose this leg which is AR20 it olny connect with r0601 resistance and the other side of the resistance is ground and i want to know is this leg importent to make iphone work or i can skip it ???

Comment: Did you try booting up without it? Does it work? Most likely it is required but it is pretty hard to be sure. If it is your phone you can take a chance, but if it is for a customer, I think you better install the resistor. Can you take one from another device that is broken? Or if not I guess you have to order the part.